# "Create an account" in multilingual site

Tags: login, multilingual, registration, t3-framework

In a multilingual joomla site, in login module. "create an account" link to the registration page, works only for one language.
As I understood this problem is for all unassigned components items (like create an account, or everything that has a not a menu item associated). They all send their output to default template. And if we use different templates for different languages, (which for example is mandatory for using megamenu in t3 framework) it can't find a place to send output.

Any idea, how to overcome this?

Comment: By default, a multilingual registration "works". What do you mean by it "does not work"?

Comment: I think that I found the reason. In t3 framework I had to define default template for each language separately.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom template framework you might need to define the template for each language - this is common in templates powered by huge overweight PHP frameworks like Gantry or T3.